# Pass image url from variable to html in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, variables

In my script, text(message.image) returns a dynamic URL path of an image. What would be the correct statement in a javascript?

This fails:

```
 $('<div/>').'<img src=\"'.text(message.image).'\">'.appendTo($('#msgDiv'));
```

Comment: Do you mean javascript?

Comment: Yes... javascript @Pphoenix

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: For concatenation in Javascript, `+` is to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real answer is:

```
$('<div><img src="'+message.image+'"/></div>').appendTo($('#msgDiv'));
```

You have a couple syntactic errata in your code snippet:

- You can't access a property with a string like you do.
- Concatenation of strings is not with a dot but with a plus.
- You are trying to execute `text()` on a string, not on the div.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing `()`,`+`,`append` method and escaping `"` incorrectly, try with this:

`$('<div/>').append('<img src="' + text(message.image) + '"/>').appendTo($('#msgDiv'));`

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem because you're using (double)quote badly

You escape the double quote but you're using simplequote. Try that :

```
$('<div/>').'<img src=\''.text(message.image).'\'>'.appendTo($('#msgDiv'));
```

And are you sure concerning the syntax $('').'SOME HTML CODE' ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `(` and `)` there.

Also, you **dont need to escape double quotes** since you are using single quotes outside.

Try this:

```
$('<div/>').('<img src="'+text(message.image)+'">').appendTo($('#msgDiv'));
```